# Setting the end date as 31/12/yyyy

Tags: oracle

I am working on reports wherein if I am running the report for the year 2021 and if my activity continues till 2022 then the end date of the activity should be set as 31/12/2021.
How can I achieve this.

Comment: "my activity continues till 2022" is not a meaningful description of your data. Do you have the data in a table, with a column for "activity end date", and if that date is beyond December 31, 2021, you want the actual date to be replaced with 31/12/2021 on the report? **That** is a technically meaningful explanation of the problem (if, in fact, that is what your data is, and what your task or requirement is). Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the year as a parameter, then such a query might return what you want:

```
SQL> select add_months(trunc(to_date(&par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'), 12) - 1 result from dual;
Enter value for par_year: 2021

RESULT
----------
31/12/2021

SQL>
```

- `to_date` converts e.g. 2021 to a valid date datatype value (it will be set to the 1st of current month of that year; at the moment, 01/06/2021)
- `trunc` resets it to 1st of current year (01/01/2021)
- `add_months` adds 12 months (which is then 01/01/2022) so you have to subtract 1 day from it to set the final result to 31/12/2021

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEAST`:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(activity_end, TO_DATE(:your_year || '1231', 'YYYYMMDD')) AS end_date
FROM   your_table
```